# How do I iterate a nested object and return all values where property is "something"

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the easiest way to return an array of values from a nested object where there is some specific property. The given object has many properties with the same name all over the place and keep in mind my object is very large and there is no pattern to where the property might be repeated..

for example:

```
var object = {
    car : { price : "100" },
    lot : { bike : { one : { price : "4" }, two { price : "16" } } }
    bread : { crust : { price : "2" } }
}

findAllValues( object, "price" ) // returns array ["100", "4", "16", "2"]
```

I've tried to use some libraries like lodash but I can't seem to get it right. Any response would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you also have an array `xyz: [{foo: 1}, {price: 0}]` ?

Comment: Show your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive function to recurse through your object and return an array.

You can use the following function; all you have to do is pass an object and the property to match.

```js
const object = {
    car : { price : "100" },
    lot : { bike : { one : { price : "4" }, two : { price : "16" } } },
    bread : { crust : { price : "2" } }
}


const findAllValues = (obj, match) => {
  const res = []
  const recurse = (obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
      const value = obj[key]
      if (value !== undefined) {
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
          recurse(value, key)
        } else {
          if (key === match) {
            res.push(value)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  recurse(obj)
  return res
}

console.log(findAllValues(object, "price"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! The only thing I noticed is that 'current' isn't getting used.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, we use a `deepSearch` function that recursively dives down any arbitrary object and, if there's a key that matches our provided `key`, we tack it on to the provided array.

```js
const object = {
    car : { price : "100" },
    lot : { bike : { one : { price : "4" }, two : { price : "16" } } },
    bread : { crust : { price : "2" } }
}

console.log(findAllValues(object, "price"));

function findAllValues(object, key) {
  const arr = [];
  deepSearch(object, key, arr);
  return arr;
}

function deepSearch(obj, key, array) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, value]) => {
    if (k === key) {
      array.push(value);
    } else if (typeof value === "object") {
      deepSearch(value, key, array);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!